# Send Multiple values from ajax to php in url with GET

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I want to send 2 values to php using ajax. When I use one variable, it works fine, but when I use 2 variables, the query no longer works in the `php` file.

```
$.ajax({ 
    url:'page.php?suplier_id='+suplierNameMain+'&quality_id='+qualityNameMain,
        method:'GET', success:function(data) {
});
```

If I use only `supplier_id`, everything works great.

P.S `qualityNameMain` shows correct value in `console.log()`

Comment: Are suplierNameMain and qualityNameMain url encoded?

Comment: nopes, but Sean's Solution is working :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure it's not related, but there is no reason to build your own query string.  Use the `data` property instead, which as Barmar points out will properly URL encode your parameters:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'page.php',
    data: {
        'suplier_id': suplierNameMain,
        'quality_id': qualityNameMain
    },
    success: function(data) {
        /* Whatever */
    }
});
```

Note that `method` from your example isn't valid for jQuery (there is a `type` setting to switch between `GET` and `POST`), but `GET` is the default so you might as well exclude it altogether.

Comment: It very well could be related. This will ensure that the values are properly URL-encoded.

Comment: No problem.  As an aside, supplier has two 'p's, not one.

Comment: lol, actually this mistake occurred right from the start and i didn't notice in the first place. when i figured that out, the project was too big to be edited, so as a matter of consistency, i left it this way :p

Answer (score 1):

Use `.ajax` like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'page.php',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {'suplier_id': suplierNameMain, 
           'quality_id': qualityNameMain
           }

    success: function(data) {
    }
 );
```