# Passing multiple values from form through AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to pass values from a form through AJAX into my SQL query file (findme.php)
I was able to follow the example from W3school, however their AJAX script only pass 1 value. Is there a way i can pass multiple values over ?

```
<form name="search" method="post" action="">
Name: <input type="text" name="findName"/>
Location: <input type="text" name="findLocation"/>
Price: <input type="text" name="findPrice"/>
<Select NAME="123">
<Option type="checkbox" value="">
<Option type="checkbox" value="=">Equal
<Option type="checkbox" value="<">Less than
<Option type="checkbox" value=">">More than
</select>

<input onclick="showUser(); return false;" type="submit" name="search" value="Search"/>
</form>
<div id="txtHint">Info will be listed here.</div>


<script>
function showUser(str) {
  if (str=="") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    return;
  } 
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","findme.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Over at my (findme.php) script, i used to have the following assigner. I am hoping that i can still pass the value into the respective variables.

```
$findName = $_POST['findName'];
$findLocation = $_POST['findLocation'];
$findPrice = $_POST['findPrice'];
$options = $_POST['123'];
```

Any idea how can this be done ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send Multiple values from ajax to php in url with GET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14346695/send-multiple-values-from-ajax-to-php-in-url-with-get)

Comment: First of all this code will not work since this line "xmlhttp.open("GET","findme.php?q="+str,true);" seems imply a get and  not a POST. Which on PHP script end will return $_POST has empty.

Comment: Not a duplicate @RakeshShetty - OP is using pure JavaScript as opposed to jQuery as pointed out in your link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do a form POST (you're using the $_POST array on the server) you can do it this way -

```
var myForm = document.getElementById('<form id>'); // add an id to the form and use it here
var formData = new FormData(myForm);
xmlhttp.open("POST","findme.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send(formData);
```

Comment: Hi @Jay Blanchard, could you explain to me how `xmlhttp.send("findName=Henry&findLocation=Washington")` works ? Is this how i send multiple value through ajax to my PHP ? Also i have notice you hvae statically assign "henry" and "washington". How do i link my text field over ?

Comment: I typically use FormData, see amended answer.

Comment: Thanks for the amended answer. it doesnt seems to be passing any value over as i keep hitting my makeshift error message for null value

Comment: I was just trying to catch null value with a simple if else statement. 
basically i got this `Notice: Undefined index: findName in D:\xampp\htdocs\findme.php on line 6` and my own echo statement telling me that value is null

Answer (score 3):

You have to send the body params of your POST request with the send() call:

```
var params = "name=value&name1=value1";
xmlhttp.send(params);
```

Your parameters needs to be URI-encoded in order to avoid issues with "&" and other reserved characters

And don't forget to change your request type to POST instead of GET

Comment: i dont really get how are you assigning the text fields over here `var params = "name=value&name1=value1";`. Care to explain to me how it is done ? CHeers